# Unable to run T4 text transformation on a build server

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, t4

We have a build server without Visual Studio 2013 installed, but we installed MSBuild tools and VS SDK that include all necessary T4 transformations files (dlls and targets). But still when I try to build the project that contains transformations on the build server I get the following error:

"...TextTemplating\v12.0\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets(396,5): error : There was a problem getting an AppDomain to run the transformation from the host. The process cannot continue. . Line=-1, Column=-1"

Everything works fine locally. I copied everything that I believe MSBuild needs to run the build. Last resort is to install Visual Studio on the build server but I don't want to do this, would like to keep the setup light.

Comment: Have you perhaps try the solution offered in [this MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9b099c10-91b1-49ca-a610-3cc383cf044d/t4-template-generation-on-build-server-fails?forum=vsx)?

Comment: Thanks, I ended up installing VS13 on the build server, and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of sweating and swearing I ended up installing VS 2013 on the build server, and this solved the problem. Not the way I wanted it to be, but at least and at last it works.